# jQuery Shopping Cart - Simple request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery Shopping Cart script I just bought.
It is great, but I need to modify it a little bit.

As you can see, there's custom attributes that are set in the JS code.
Right now, "minimum" and "price" are custom attributes, but I would add the "gap" attribute.
So what I need is :

```
1- To be able to set the "quantity gap". By that I mean :
if (custom attribute of the product ul)gap="1"...then when add more of this item, go up by 1 in the shoppping cart

if gap="2"...then go up by 2
if gap="3"...then go up by 3...
and so on. You get the idea.
```

Here's the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dSj5U/

I have copied the whole Javascript part, and a part of the HTML. So don't look at the HTML render...it's just for you to see how it works.

This is very important for us, since we are working on a big project using this shopping cart. We would highly appreciate if someone could help.

Thank you!

Comment: And why don't you ask the company you bought it from?

Comment: I emailed the guy, but he said he could only do something in 2 weeks. So I thought that it would be faster using StackOverflow's help. Because we really need this to be done this week

Answer (score 1):

I have found it by myself.

I added the "gap" custom attribute, and then added :

```
        if(v < settings.productBuyLimit) v += g;
```

"g" being "gap: parseFloat(product.attr('gap'+option))

"v" being the cart_item.quantity